# How to remove all fields except field with specified name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the form with several hidden inputs, with names `name="hidden1"`, `name="hidden2"` and `name="hidden3"`, for example. The script below remove all of this inputs:

```
if ($(this.form).children(':hidden')) {
   $(this.form).children(':hidden').remove();
}
```

But i need that it remove all inputs except `name=hidden3`.

I guess that it is simple task. But i'm newbie in js and i don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter using jQuery's not() http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$(this.form).children(':hidden').not('[name="hidden3"]').remove();
```